# How to force user to update an app on Android with python?

Tags: python, android, google-play

I saw [good posts](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) talking about the API to do it in Java/C++/C#. Do we have an equivalent for python ?

(I suppose with because PyQt and kivy app gonna need it and there are ways to encapsulate java/c++ code into python code)
But I don't how.